# why my code run wrong ,it is about '@property'

Tags: python

I used python 2.5, I want to know how can change the next code when the Platform is python2.5 or python2.6

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x

a=C()
print a.x#error
```

thanks

---

thanks ,alex,i think property must be 3 arguments in your example

but ,i have seen a code which with 'property' only use 1 argumennt ,why,can it work

```
class SortingMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        request.__class__.field = property(get_field)
        request.__class__.direction = property(get_direction)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2.5 does not support the `.setter` and `.deleter` sub-decorators of `property`; they were introduced in Python 2.6.

To work on both releases, you can, instead, code something like:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def _get_x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x
    def _set_x(self, value):
        self._x = value
    def _del_x(self):
        del self._x
    x = property(_get_x, _set_x, _del_x)
```

Comment: thanks ,alex,i think property must be 3 arguments in your example

but ,i have seen a code which with 'property' only use 1 argumennt ,why,can it work

Comment: `property` in 2.5 can be called with just one argument (or, equivalently, as a decorator) when you want the property to be read-only (only a getter: no setter, no deleter).

Comment: The `property` function has 4 arguments (getter, setter and deleter and documentation). The last parameter is not really relevant to this discussion so we'll ignore it. The other three default to None which means that the property cannot be "gotten", "set" or "deleted". (if a parameter is None, that action is considered not doable). When you call it with a single argument, only the "getter" method (ie. the first parameter) is specified so it becomes a 'read only' attribute and the other two operations (set and delete) are disallowed.

Comment: I know this is old, but this answer and the comments helped me immensely.